# Factor programming language: setting-up .factor-roots configuration

Tags: stack, factor-lang, concatenative-language

I downloaded the [Factor](http://factorcode.org) programming language for Mac. I can now launch the command `factor` from the command line successfully. I read in a book covering this language *(Seven More Languages in...)* that, to run standalone programs I need to indicate the root paths from which Factor will search for vocabularies. I thus have to create a `.factor-roots` file in my home directory indicating the full paths to the root directories where I have my Factor source files, one path per line. My factor folder is in the `/Applications` folder. factor directory contains:

```
Factor.app          git-id
README.md           libfactor-ffi-test.dylib
basis               libfactor.dylib
core                license.txt
extra               misc
factor              work
factor.image
```

What should I exactly write in the `.factor-roots` file, to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED: I have to write into the `.factor-roots` file the path to the directory into which I write my standalone programs, not the path to the Factor installation directory.

Comment: You should accept the answer. Also take a look in the Vocabulary Roots topic in documentation if you have more doubts.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different ways to do this described in [the docs](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-add-vocab-roots.html). I've tried all three, and had some trouble with all of them, which lead me to this post.

I tried setting the `FACTOR_ROOTS` environment variable, but this didn't work at all. Not sure if this was an error on my part.

The other two methods are more successful.

Either create a file ~/.factor-roots (loaded at Factor startup) and add the path to your vocabulary root (without quotation marks).

Or create a file ~/.factor-rc (also loaded at Factor startup but can contain any code you'd like to call when Factor starts) and pass in your vocabulary root path as a parameter to the `add-vocab-root` word. My ~/.factor-rc contains the following:

```
USE: editors EDITOR: editors.visual-studio-code
USE: vocabs.loader
"/path/to/your/vocabulary/root" add-vocab-root
```

The `vocabs.loader` vocabulary is necessary to call `add-vocab-root`.

It took me a while to figure out that these two files need to be located in the home directory, not in the root of the Factor source.